# Find the value associated with the next bigger number in a sorted range

Tags: google-sheets, match, formula

I would like to find the first cell from `H31:H61` that is bigger than the one in `H28` and then output the number from ColumnF of the corresponding row:

[image: my spreadsheet screenshot]

Can someone help me write the formula in `H29` for that?

Comment: Thank you for editing it pnuts. This is my first time using stackoverflow. Need to get used to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=QUERY(F31:H,"select F where H > "&H28&" limit 1",0)`

This assumes the values in H31:H are sorted ascending. If this assumption is not correct:

`=QUERY(F31:H,"select F where H > "&H28&" order by H limit 1",0)`

Comment: Oh so you can use QUERYs like in SQL in spreadsheets? Cool!
AdamL your formula throws an error. I had to change the "," to ";" and it works perfectly now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I found another way to solve this problem.
`=INDIRECT("F"&(MATCH(H28;H32:H61;1)+32))`

The example with QUERY doesn't work if the value in H28 is generated dynamicaly, but this way it does work.

Comment: +pnuts: wouldn't `=match(H28,H31:H61)` return a result that is smaller/equal to? (rather than bigger) [edit] although you could reference the next one down from that result I suppose, which is what I think the OP is doing in the commented solution.

Comment: Yes @AdamL that's exactly what I am doing with that +32 after the MATCH(). +1 would be ok to make it bigger then, but since my F numbers start at F31 I need +32.